# print start of html tags

Tags: regex

I want to print out the first html tags thats has attributes

```
    <h1>test</h1>
    <h2>test2</h2>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <p>test3</p>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div id="nav"></div>
    <p>test3</p>
```

for instance, given the above html I want to print

```
<div class="content">
<div id="nav">
```

I try this but I get the blow result instead:

```
="content">
="nav">
```

---

```
import re
file = open('test.html')
test = file.read()
lines = test.splitlines()
b= re.findall(r'<?=.*?>',test)
for a in b:
    print(a)
```

how to I adjust my code to get the right output.

Comment: So are you saying that you want HTML tags with only _one_ attribute (and hence `<div id="content" class="test"></div>` does not appear in the output)?

Comment: Don't use regular expressions. Use an HTML parser, like BeautifulSoup. You also don't seem to have considered how you want to handle nested elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a non-greedy match for any number of characters to the left of the `=`, so:

```
r'<.*?=.*?>'
```

That will match a `<`, followed by a minimum number of characters, followed by a `=`, followed by the minimum number of characters until the `>`.

What you had:

```
r'<?=.*?>'
```

Means an optional `<`, followed by a `=`, followed by any string going up to the `>`. Since the `<` is optional and would only match if *right before* the `=`, you end up with no matches for it.

Comment: Fails on `'<div>=</div>'`. Nevermind `CDATA` elements. Regular expressions on HTML are never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty complicated, you can try with this expression, but it would fail in some cases. It would first collect the undesired instances, then at the end there is a capturing group for those desired.

Maybe, it wouldn't be the best idea to use regular expressions here.

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"^\s*<\S+>\s*$|^\s*<\S+\s.*test.*?>.*?<\/\S+>$|^\s*(<.*>)\s*$"

test_str = """

<h1>test</h1>
    <h2>test2</h2>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <p>test3</p>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div id="nav"></div>
    <p>test3</p>

"""

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.M))
```

#### Output

```
['', '', '<div id="content"></div>', '', '', '<div id="nav"></div>', '']
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/IOspgT/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/IOspgT/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.